# apex trigger copy record after opportunity update

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am relatively new to Apex and trigger writing. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Is it possible to copy a record in a custom object into a new record that was created within the same object? In my case, when an opportunity is set to "close won" I need to create a new record in the custom object called Project__c. But the kicker is there is an existing record named proj1 that contains default data that needs to be copied into every new record that goes into the object Project__c.

I know how to create a new record after update on Opportunity, but I'm unsure how to grab the record proj1 out of the object Project__c and copy it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your default data Project__c record using SOQL and clone it as the basis for the new object that will be inserted. To do this you will want to use the [sObject.clone()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone) method.

E.g.

```
List<Project__c> toUpdate = new List<Project__c>();

// You might want to consider how you identify this template record. 
// E.g. Custom Setting with the record Id or unique name
// Make sure you select the fields you want to clone.
List<Project__c> templateProjects = [Select 
         Id, Name, OtherCustomFields__c, ThatShouldBeCloned__c 
         from Project__c where Name = 'proj1' limit 1];
if(templateProjects.size() == 1) {
    Project__c templateProject = templateProjects[0];
    // The default opt_preserve_id param in clone won't clone the Id.
    Project__c opportunityProject = templateProject.clone();

    // Set any fields based on the Opportunity that weren't cloned from the template record
    opportunityProject.OpportunitySpecificCustomField__c = opp.Name;

    toUpdate.add(opportunityProject);
} else {
     // What should you do if there isn't a template record available?
}

insert toUpdate;
```

Incidentally, there is a dedicated [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) for Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! This helped me finish my trigger.